# Random distribution of items in list up to a maximum count

Tags: java, list, distribution

I have a `List` of items containing x items.

I want to distribute these items randomly in other Lists with the conditions :

> - Each List has a maximum size of y item (with y = 4)
> - Each Item must be used a maximum of z times (with z = 5)

If x isn't divisible by both y and z, it's okay to have Lists containing less than y items.

I'm looking for a Java (from 1.6 to 1.8) implementation of such a method. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's what I tried so far :

```
List<Item> myItems;  // Initialized in an other part
int y, z;            // Initialized in an other part
int x = myItems.size();
List<List<Item>> myList = new ArrayList<List<Item>>();
int a = (int) Math.ceil((double)x/y);

Random random = new Random(new Random().nextInt());

for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
    myList.add(j, new ArrayList<Item>());
}

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    int r = random.nextInt(a);
    while (myList.get(r).size() >= y) {
        r = random.nextInt(a);
    }
    myList.get(r).add(myItems.get(i));
}

// Here myList is populated
```

Comment: Do you want something that's uniformly distributed?  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Please add what you've tried.

Comment: It seems you now need to keep track of how many times each item in the list has been used (and compare against `z`).

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes, as of right now, I get Lists containing between 0 and 1 occurence of my Items up to their maximum size.

Comment: It's not clear when you should stop adding things to the lists. Is it when you've added `x` items?  Or when all `x/y` lists are full?

Comment: @JamieCockburn I need to have a number of Lists such as each item is used z times and each list contains a maximum of y items. Also, each list can only contain one occurence of a particular item.

Comment: Since you specify `int a = (int) Math.ceil((double)x/y);` then each item will only occur in the lists maxmium one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work.  I've assumed here that the total number of items in the list shouldn't change.

```
public List<List<Item>> distribute(List<Item> list, int y, int z) {
    int x = list.size();
    int nLists = (int) Math.ceil((double)x/y);

    // Create result lists
    List<List<Item>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < nLists; j++)
        result.add(new ArrayList<Item>());
    List<List<Item>> outputLists = new ArrayList<>(result);

    // Create item count store
    Map<Item, Integer> itemCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (Item item : list)
        itemCounts.put(item, 0);

    // Populate results
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        // Add a random item (from the remaining eligible items)
        // to a random list (from the remaining eligible lists)
        Item item = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
        List<Item> outputList = outputLists.get(random.nextInt(outputLists.size()));
        outputList.add(item);

        // Manage eligible output lists
        if (outputList.size() >= y)
            outputLists.remove(outputList);

        // Manage eligible items
        int itemCount = itemCounts.get(item).intValue() + 1;
        if (itemCount >= z)
            list.remove(item);
        else
            itemCounts.put(item, itemCount);
    }

    return result;
}
```

*Note: the above code mutates the original list.  If that is not desired, you should create a copy of the list at the start.*

With the following input:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]   
y = 4
z = 3
```

This gives output lists such as:

```
[1,10,17,2]
[2,24,6,26]
[16,23,21]
[8,0,3,13]
[12,11,6,0]
[2,17,14,7]
[0,27,7,12]
[7,19,3]
```

During that run, items `0`, `2`, and `7` reached the `z` limit, and were not used again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is really great! I unfortunately just had to revise my specs a bit : `z` must now be the `exact` amount of occurence of each item and not just the `maximum`. I'm gonna try working it out with your code, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thrax Can you accept the answer then?  You should post a new question if you're changing the problem.

Comment: By the way, is there any reason why you don't directly populate `outputList` with `new ArrayList<Item>()` at the beginning?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  `outputlists` is an `ArrayList<List<Item>>`, it is initialised from the `result` array (it starts out as a copy of that list).

Comment: What i was asking is why you copy `results` in `outputList` instead of populating directly `outputList` in your loop with `new ArrayList<Item>()`

Comment: `results` contains all of the final lists.  `outputLists` contains only the lists that are not yet full (which at the start is all of them).  I don't populate `outputLists` directly, because it's less code just to populate `results` and copy it. In theory, it is also possibly more efficient, because java is doing the copy, which could be optimised by the JVM, rather than doing  it element by element.

Comment: I created a new question with revised specs, if you want to take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544808/random-distribution-of-items-in-list-with-exact-number-of-occurences. Thanks again!